# recursive algorithm to print given display?

Tags: recursion, permutation

I'm working on a problem dealing with recursion. I'm supposed to pass in two ints into a function, which represent a number of N objects and M values that I must find all permutations of. I am also given a sample of what the output is supposed to look like

```
void perm_rec_1(int N, int nr_values)
```

and the output this is supposed to print is :

```
Called : perm_rec_1(3, 2);

0  0  0
0  0  1
0  1  0
0  1  1
1  0  0
1  0  1
1  1  0
1  1  1
```

I understand the concept of recursion by using a swap function to change the orders of strings to find all permutations of a string, but I'm unsure of how to apply it here, or if it even can. It looks like the array changes by changing the end of the array by increasing the element by one up to nr_vals-1.
any help would be appreciated, and thank you for your time.

Comment: such problem is more easily fixed with a loop. It is just counting in base "nr_values" with "N" digits, any recursion would just be more complex thanplain loop, recursion is more usefull when you have fixed number of elements that should be permutated (here you just find all combinations wich is "counting")

Comment: wich programming language?

Comment: I'm using c. and I agree with you, and that is actually also what I need to do. the task I need to complete is come up with a recursive design for finding these permutations as well as an iterative(loop) algorithm. I think I'm close to solving the iterative one though.

Comment: If the problem can be solved with loop approach => recursive immediatly follows.

If the problem can be solved only with recursive => then the only loop solution requires usage of heap allocated stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't mentioned any language here's C++ version:

```
#include <iostream>

void perm_rec_1_aux( int *values, int N, int nr, int curr, int idx);
void print_val( int * values, int N);

void perm_rec_1( int N, int nr){
    int * values = new int[N]; //replace with malloc for C
    for( int i= 0; i<nr; i++)
        perm_rec_1_aux( values, N, nr, i, 0);

    delete [] values; //replace with free for C
}

void print_val( int * values, int N){
    // use printf for C
    for(int i = 0; i<N; i++)
        std::cout<< values[i]<<" ";
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}

void perm_rec_1_aux( int *values, int N, int nr, int curr, int idx){
    values[idx] = curr;

    if( idx+1 == N)
        return print_val(values, N);

    for( int i=0; i<nr; i++)
        perm_rec_1_aux( values, N, nr, i, idx+1);
}

int main() {
    perm_rec_1( 3, 2);
    std::cout<<"--\n";
    perm_rec_1( 2, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
0 1 1
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 1 0
1 1 1
--
0 0
0 1
0 2
1 0
1 1
1 2
2 0
2 1
2 2
```

Answer (score 0):

So out of curiosity, what would the loop(iterative) version look like?
I'm assuming it's nested loops based on N and nr_vals?

Comment: add 1 to rightmost value, if it becomes = nr then set it to zero and add 1 to value immediatly at it left, and so on. should be 2/3 loops